# Pandas Agg(lamba x: np.mean (x== something)

Tags: python, pandas

Please explain how does the lambda function works here?

I understood that it is counting (days with 2)/(total number monday day) for monday category. Same for Tuesday.

but i can't understand the logic behind lambda and np.mean.

[image]

Also, Why does't below return the result as above, eg:0.3333? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x==2` returns a boolean array, e.g. `[True, False, False, False]` for `'Monday'` (rows 0, 4, 5, and 8). Within `np.mean` these boolean values are cast to `[1, 0, 0, 0]` and the mean of this array is `0.25`.

---

As for the second question: if you don't group then `x` is the value of each row, e.g. `2` for row 0. `2==2` returns `True` and `np.mean(True) == np.mean(1) == 1.0`.

To get a better understanding what's going on you can output `x` like so:

```
def agg_fun(x):
    print(f"--- called with {type(x).__name__} ---:\n{x}\n{'='*27}")
    return np.mean(x==2)

dd.agg(agg_fun)
```

To fully understand the behavior of `agg` you'll have to carefully read the [documentation for the first parameter `func`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html):

> Function to use for aggregating the data. If a function, must either
> work when passed a Series or when passed to Series.apply.

In fact the function is first **applied** to the series (i.e. called on each element) and only if this fails it is **called** with the series as its argument, see [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/9d598a5e1eee26df95b3910e3f2934890d062caa/pandas/core/series.py#L3952-L3963). Take for instance the following example:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2])
s.agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))
```

This function **can be applied** and we receive

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
```

By contrast, `s.agg(lambda x: x.mean())` (which is the same as `s.agg(np.mean)`) **cannot be appied** to a series (an `int` has no attribute `mean`), so this error is catched and a second try is made to **call the function** with the series as parameter. This works without error and we receive `1.5`.

Comment: Hi Thanks! could you please further explain why if i dont use with groupby it does'nt return the same result (Please see my edit)? i expecting it to return 0.33333.

Comment: Hi thanks, my though is that. If first example, `df. groupby('Days'). agg(np. mean)` will return the mean value for monday, while for second example `dd. agg(np. mean) ` will also return a mean for entire series. But the lambda x, it behave differently for groupby and without groupby. Can again please explain why the first example with groupby, the lambda x will return a list of boolean under monday & tuesday? Thanks

Comment: @josephgan: please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort!! I got it for the 2nd example (without groupby). First example still have a little understanding to be confirmed left. So if i use groupby, any function called, will be applied to the **entire series** as parameter. It will not look into individual row (not because it cannot be applied), so the logic for `df.groupby('Days').agg(lambda x: np.mean(x==2))` 1. It first create  Series for each group in 'Days' 2. Lambda x will return boolean for x==2 for the **Entire Series**. 3. Then np.mean will be apply to the **Entire Series**. Is my understanding correct Thanks!

Comment: @josephgan yes, this is correct. I also modified `agg_fun` in my answer a bit for better diagnostics.